# How to use awk to extract the first word after -> character

Tags: shell

I have a unix script where i need to extract cycle numbers following the symbolic link

for example:

the location /test1/test2/test3/test4 points to ../c2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite

```
so ls -l /test1/test2/test3/test4 -> ../c2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
```

I need to extract c2.3. I tried using awk -F/ '{print $5}' . It works only if c2.3 is at 5th position. how can we write the script to print if the position changes?

for example ls -l /test1/test2/test3/test4/test5 -> ../c2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite 
can awk print text after -> .., please let me know! Many thanks!

Vidya

Answer (score 3):

Parsing `ls -l` is a complication you don't need. Try this:

```
readlink /test1/test2/test3/test4/test5 | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Amadan is right, parsing `ls` is not recommended, and I don't touch that part of the question. I understood that the goal is to extract the c2.3 wherever it occurs in the input string. So I created some test input, with a few variations on the given theme:

```
[cycle_number $] cat test.in
../c2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/test6_Suite/c2.4/
../output/c2.5/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/c6.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/c6.81/test6_Suite
../output/test5/c136.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/c36.809/test6_Suite

../a2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/test6_Suite/b2.4/
../output/c2.5/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/d6.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/e6.81/test6_Suite
../output/test5/f136.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/g36.809/test6_Suite

../ab2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/test6_Suite/abc2.4/
../output/abcd2.5/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/d6.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/e6.81/test6_Suite
../output/test5/f136.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/g36.809/test6_Suite


[cycle_number $]
```

The following sed script extracts the number and prints it at the start of the line:

```
[cycle_number $] sed 's|^.*\/\([a-zA-Z]\+[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)\/.*$|\1 &|' test.in
c2.3 ../c2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
c2.4 ../output/test5/test6_Suite/c2.4/
c2.5 ../output/c2.5/test5/test6_Suite
c6.8 ../output/test5/c6.8/test6_Suite
c6.81 ../output/test5/c6.81/test6_Suite
c136.8 ../output/test5/c136.8/test6_Suite
c36.809 ../output/test5/c36.809/test6_Suite

a2.3 ../a2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
b2.4 ../output/test5/test6_Suite/b2.4/
c2.5 ../output/c2.5/test5/test6_Suite
d6.8 ../output/test5/d6.8/test6_Suite
e6.81 ../output/test5/e6.81/test6_Suite
f136.8 ../output/test5/f136.8/test6_Suite
g36.809 ../output/test5/g36.809/test6_Suite

ab2.3 ../ab2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
abc2.4 ../output/test5/test6_Suite/abc2.4/
abcd2.5 ../output/abcd2.5/test5/test6_Suite
d6.8 ../output/test5/d6.8/test6_Suite
e6.81 ../output/test5/e6.81/test6_Suite
f136.8 ../output/test5/f136.8/test6_Suite
g36.809 ../output/test5/g36.809/test6_Suite



[cycle_number $]
```

Obviously, you can remove the last `&` if you don't want the original line. Feel free to post more details if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, sed works aswell. I tried this for different combinations in the path that has symbolic links, works well.

Answer (score 1):

here's a gawk solution:

```
[cycle_number $] cat test.in
../c2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite          
../output/test5/test6_Suite/c2.4/         
../output/c2.5/test5/test6_Suite          
../output/test5/c6.8/test6_Suite          
../output/test5/c6.81/test6_Suite         
../output/test5/c136.8/test6_Suite        
../output/test5/c36.809/test6_Suite       

../a2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/test6_Suite/b2.4/
../output/c2.5/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/d6.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/e6.81/test6_Suite
../output/test5/f136.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/g36.809/test6_Suite

../ab2.3/output/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/test6_Suite/abc2.4/
../output/abcd2.5/test5/test6_Suite
../output/test5/d6.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/e6.81/test6_Suite
../output/test5/f136.8/test6_Suite
../output/test5/g36.809/test6_Suite



[cycle_number $] cat cn.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS="/"
}

{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){

        if(match($i, /[a-z]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)){
            print $i
        }
    }

}
[cycle_number $] ./cn.awk test.in
c2.3
c2.4
c2.5
c6.8
c6.81
c136.8
c36.809
a2.3
b2.4
c2.5
d6.8
e6.81
f136.8
g36.809
ab2.3
abc2.4
abcd2.5
d6.8
e6.81
f136.8
g36.809
[cycle_number $]
```